# Is a Garmin eTrex GPS compatible?

Tags: usb, gps

I would like to plug in an old GPS as an NTP source. The GPSD and [OpenStreetMap documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/USB_Garmin_on_GNU/Linux) cover the use but I am stuck at a point where I am not sure the device is compatible (though it should be). The device itself has satellites fixed and is functional.

Specifically, the [GPSD documentation](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/troubleshooting.html) states

> Try running `gpsmon(1)`, giving it your GPS device path as an argument
>   (for example `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0`). After a few moments to sync up,
>   it should display a screen full of data on the device, including
>   displaying the raw packet data streaming from it.
>
> If `gpsmon(1)` reports no data at all, you may have the device path
>   wrong; check that using `dmesg(8)` or by whatever means you have
>   available. If you have the right device, you may have some low-level
>   system problem with serial or USB that you'll need to fix before
>   `gpsd` will operate. Check your cabling, power, and kernel
>   configuration.

I am with the latter problem: there is nothing displyed by `gpsmon` (the screen is cleared and is completely blank).

It looks like the device is registered correctly. From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan  1 21:20:11 srv kernel: [ 7076.457051] usbcore: registered new interface driver garmin_gps
Jan  1 21:20:11 srv kernel: [ 7076.457061] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Garmin GPS usb/tty
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv kernel: [ 7148.510660] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv kernel: [ 7148.651115] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=091e, idProduct=0003
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv kernel: [ 7148.651116] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv kernel: [ 7148.651553] garmin_gps 1-2:1.0: Garmin GPS usb/tty converter detected
Jan  1 21:21:23 srv kernel: [ 7148.651623] usb 1-2: Garmin GPS usb/tty converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Cannot assign requested address
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: Failed to listen on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Manage ttyUSB0 for GPS daemon.
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: gpsdctl@ttyUSB0.service: Job gpsdctl@ttyUSB0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan  1 21:22:40 srv kernel: [ 7225.003241] pps pps0: new PPS source usbserial0
Jan  1 21:22:40 srv kernel: [ 7225.003246] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyUSB0" added
```

The last two lines appear after `gpsmon` is started and look promising but there are a few lines above which are worrisome, though:

```
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Cannot assign requested address
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: Failed to listen on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Manage ttyUSB0 for GPS daemon.
Jan  1 21:21:24 srv systemd[1]: gpsdctl@ttyUSB0.service: Job gpsdctl@ttyUSB0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

I am not sure if they are critial at this point, as they mention sockets - which I do not use yet (or at all).

The troubleshooting section does not really help -- what steps should I actually take from there on?

Comment: In general the answer is that you can't. Accurate timekeeping requires a pulse per second. It does not look like you can do that. Furthermore, USB is a crappy choice, since the protocol is not deterministic with regards to time. You're better off syncing against a random stratum 2 NTP server. I've seen some cheap (15-20$) USB GPS'es which has PPS available at the board - which can for instance be connected to a GPIO on a RPi quite easily.

Comment: @vidarlo: thanks for the information. I currently synchronize to stratum 2 sources and this is more then enough for my needs. I was hoping for a useful retirement for an old device which I will otherwise recycle.

Comment: Ok :) First of all - have you set up gpsd? If not, can you try running `gpsd -n -N -D 3 -G /dev/ttyUSB0`, and `gpsmon` in a seperate terminal? [Edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Er, sorry about the weird onslaught of comments. Since I'm here, I'm wondering whether you ever managed to figure this out. It's never too late to post an answer, if you remember what it was!

Comment: @Zanna: I did not go further after vidarlo's sensible comment (that the precision of the setup I want to build is not good). I wanted to use my old GPS to expose myself as an NTP source for the community (ntp.org)  with reasonable precision. Not having the GPS did not make sense for that and I fell back to being a lower stratum server.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot for the update :)